# Flutter: type 'DateTime' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Tags: flutter, datetime, google-cloud-firestore

```
Text(
        DateTime.parse(documents[index]['createdAt']
                                  .toDate()
                                  .toString()) ??
                              'default',
)
```

I am trying to get date from firestore. I have DateTime.now() stored in createdIn in firestore.

Comment: Maybe `Text(DateTime.parse(documents[index]['createdAt'].toDate().toString()).toString() ??'default',)`

Comment: Is there reason to parse data string to DateTime type?(Maybe for date formatting?) If not, you just remove 'DateTime.parse'.

Answer (score 1):

because the format of both is not the same.

1. step 1: you can create DateFormat.
2. step 2: use 'DateFormat'.parse().

try reading this: https://help.talend.com/r/6K8Ti_j8LkR03kjthAW6fg/atMe2rRCZqDW_Xjxy2Wbqg

Answer (score 1):

Here, it is expecting type as 'String', but we are passing it as a 'DateTime' which is incorrect.

Formatting dates in the default 'en_US' format does not require any initialization.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html

So, we simply need to format it like:

```
var dateTime = DateTime.now()
DateFormat.E().format(dateTime)
```

E() is the constructor of DateFormat in Flutter which refers to first 3 letter of the week

You can refer the official doc for available constructors:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html#constructors

**Note**:
Below is the version used for DateTime library ~ intl
intl: ^0.18.0

(https://pub.dev/packages/intl)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Timestamp field, cast it to Timestamp.  If you need that as a DateTime, use a .toDate on that.  Don't process it through a string... completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

It might help you

```
  String? changeDateFormatWithInput(String? currentDate, currentFormat,
  requiredFormat) {
String? date;

try {
  if (currentDate != null && currentDate.isNotEmpty) {
    DateTime tempDate =
    new DateFormat(currentFormat).parse(currentDate, true);
    date = DateFormat(requiredFormat).format(tempDate.toLocal());
    return date;
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
  return null;
}
return date;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
Text(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateTime.parse(_DoctorTimeSlot[index]['start_Time'].toString())).toString() ??'default',)
```